# Redis in action example

Tags: python, redis

From the "Redis in Action" book I was reading I saw the following  example and now I'm wondering if this is correct or not. The example has the following code in python:

```
def purchase_item(conn, buyerid, itemid, sellerid, lprice):
buyer = "users:%s"%buyerid
seller = "users:%s"%sellerid
item = "%s.%s"%(itemid, sellerid)
inventory = "inventory:%s"%buyerid
end = time.time() + 10
pipe = conn.pipeline()


while time.time() < end:
    try:
        pipe.watch("market:", buyer)                #A
        price = pipe.zscore("market:", item)        #B
        funds = int(pipe.hget(buyer, "funds"))      #B
        if price != lprice or price > funds:        #B
            pipe.unwatch()                          #B
            return None


        pipe.multi()                                #C
        pipe.hincrby(seller, "funds", int(price))   #C
        pipe.hincrby(buyer, "funds", int(-price))   #C
        pipe.sadd(inventory, itemid)                #C
        pipe.zrem("market:", item)                  #C
        pipe.execute()                              #C
        return True
    except redis.exceptions.WatchError:             #D
        pass                                        #D


return False
```

As you can see this example uses pipelining, and from what I have understand, the commands aren't executed until pipe.execute() is called. In this example you see at #B an if statement, but is the price value returned here or not? Or is the code exectution somehow buffered when conn.pipeline() is called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the `redis-py` library. When you call `pipe.watch()`, the pipeline is put into *execution* mode with immediate effect. So you're able to use regular python code to check the return values of subsequent commands. You can put the pipeline in *buffered* mode again, by using `pipe.multi()` which is exactly what the code is doing. The last `pipe.execute()` is only to execute the commands marked "#C" in your code. All this is explained in the [redis-py docs](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#pipelines). To summarize:

```
pipe.watch(...) # <--- executed immediately
pipe.zscore(...) # <--- executed immediately
.....
pipe.multi() # <--- put pipeline back in *buffered* mode
pipe.incr(..) # <--- buffered command 1
pipe.incr(..) # <--- buffered command 2
pipe.execute() # <--- execute buffered commands 1 and 2
```